# Asp.net Core Boilerplate, how to implement multiple dbcontext based on tenant

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to implement a project using asp.net core boilerplate framework. Certain Requirements force me to not use the multiple database approach of abp, but instead i have common tables like users info etc in default Database but tenant related data products/programs etc in multiple databases. 
In short dbcontext will be somewhat dynamic based on tenant.

1. One way i found is to get dbcontext based on tenant and then in every function:

   `Using(tenantDbcontext)
   {
       //logic
   }`
2. But i find this way to be unsatisfactory, as for every function i will be doing it this way. Do any of you guys know another way of handling this? May be making custom repository  and injecting dbcontext based on tenant, or any other cleaner way?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework). And here you'll find a great [pdf](http://ramblingsofraju.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Multi-Tenant-Data-Architecture.pdf) about 3 common approches.

Comment: I appreciate your reply and have read these articles, but I am looking to some concrete implementation on how to get dynamic dbcontext using Abp Repository or something else, so I don't have to write using statements in every function.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you're looking for a way to implementing a repository like Abp repository?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.